# Saving the filename into sql database and running ssis package at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Scenario: I am developing a web application that allows users to upload Excel files into their respective tables in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I am also running an ETL process developed using SSIS when the user clicks on the upload button.

My development environment: Asp.net, IIS7, C#, SQL Server 2008 R2

I am currently facing the problem of saving the file name of the file into another column in the tables as I will also be creating gridview function for the user to view the files that have already been uploaded into the database and enables the users to download the error files.

Question: are there any ways I can save the file name into the same tables while running the SSIS packages during the ETL process?

Below are a sample example of my codes:

```
string filePath1 = Server.MapPath(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName.ToString()));
file.SaveAs(filePath1);

package = app.LoadPackage(packageString, null);
package.Connections["Excel Connection Manager"].ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath1 + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
```

This method allows me to retrieve the fileName :

```
String.Format("File : {0} uploaded.", file.FileName)
```

So when I execute the package, how do I save the file name to the tables at the same time?

Comment: i managed to solve the issue:

Comment: string connectionString = DAO.GetConnectionString();
                            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                            sqlConn.Open()
                            strQuery = "update uploadSummaryDB set fileName = @fileName where id in (select max(id) from uploadSummaryDB)";
                            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery,sqlConn);
                            command.Parameters.Add("@fileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = file.FileName.ToString();
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Glad to know you solved your problem. Please post your answer as an answer. That way, other people can get more benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  string connectionString = DAO.GetConnectionString(); 
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
 sqlConn.Open() 
strQuery = "update uploadSummaryDB set fileName = @fileName where id in (select max(id) from uploadSummaryDB)"; 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery,sqlConn); 
command.Parameters.Add("@fileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = file.FileName.ToString(); command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```